# Equalization of Square Pulse in Visible Light Communication

Tags: communication, receiver, optoelectronics

I am currently working on a VLC project to build a VLC receiver. I attached a schematic of the circuit I have designed. The circuit on the left is the transmitter sending a square signal at 1 MHz using the CREE RGB LED. I am receiving the signal at the other end using a OSRAM photo-diode and passing it through front end amplifier to amplify the received signal. Later its sent through a 1st order equalization circuit, to fix my distorted square wave signal. I amunsure whether my equalization circuit is correct since I do not see any change in the signal when I implement this circuit. I also experience a ringing (overshoot and oscillations to settle down) in the output waveform. Could you please help me understand the how I can equalize to get a better response to get a cleaner square wave and also to reduce the ringing in my circuit. Any response is much appreciated. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As shown (with no output load) the signal at Vout will not be affected much at all by your RC "equalizer".  If you were to place a low value resistive load (maybe 100 ohms or lower) from Vout to ground you should then see a better response.  If the added load doesn't give a satisfactory square wave then you might even consider placing a simple high speed comparator circuit after the AD8010.  To limit the frequency response of the AD8010 (and reduce oscillations etc.) also consider placing a very small value capacitor across the 10k, (low pf range).  The added capacitor would help to give a smooth pulse to the comparator,(if used), then the comparator can further square up the signal.  In addition be sure to use bypass capacitors at all power pins.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in a digital (binary ) signal - I.e. the output should be either high or low, a simple Schmitt trigger circuit would work well for this. It would produce a square signal at its output from the photodiode output.